# Readonly preseted values in Angular

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Angular and TypeScript and in the process of mastering those, I run upon a task where I need an object (or something alike) which gives me the opportunity to define an attribute which is readable but not editable.

In Java I would have done it like this

```
public class Dto {
 private long id;
 private String desc;

 public Dto(String desc){
   this.desc = desc;
   id= Generator.getRandomId();
 }

 //Getter for both
 // Setter for desc
}
```

Is there any way to do something similar in TypeScript?
I was told to do this with an Interface but by this time, I'm quite overasked.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much the same in TS :

```
class Dto {
    private readonly id: number;
    private desc: string;

    public Dto(desc: string) {
        this.desc = desc;
        this.id = Generator.getRandomId();
    }
}
```

or with an interface :

```
interface Foo {
    readonly id: string;
    desc: string;
}

declare const foo: Foo;
foo.id = '' // Error
```